# Why is callback in producer.send method not being executed during failure to send a message?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am currently sending messages to kafka like so:

```
try {
    producer.send(record, new Callback() {
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
            System.out.println(metadata);
            System.out.println(e);
            if (e != null)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                try
                {
                    throw(e);
                } catch (InvalidTopicException er) {
                    logger.error("Unrecoverable error: ", er);
                    System.exit(-1);
                } //...otherfatalexceptions...
                catch (UnknownServerException er) {
                    logger.error("Unrecoverable error: ", er);
                    System.exit(-1);
                }catch (Exception er) {
                    logger.error("Failed to send message to topic:" + topic, er);
                }
            }
        }
        });
}catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Failed to send message to topic:" + topic, e);
}
```

i am using producer.send and not waiting for the record metadata to be returned before sending the next record in a queue since it would take to long.
Instead i am using `onCallback` method to handle that data.

The idea behind the code is to terminate the program in case i get an unrecoverable error.

Producer is being initialized like so:

```
producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
```

with following properties

```
Properties mainKafkaProperties = new Properties();
mainKafkaProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaUrl);
mainKafkaProperties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
mainKafkaProperties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
mainKafkaProperties.put("acks", "all");
```

When messages are being sent properly, System.out.println(metadata); line is properly printing metadata showing that messages are being sent properly,
but when i delete the topic to simulate the `InvalidTopicException` instead of executing the code in the catch method i only get the following warning:
`[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 97 : {em_om_messages_local=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}`

Kafka library used is: org.apache.kafka.clients
I am running the program on eclipse debugger

I am getting the same error regardless how many partitions the topic has
Java version 17.0.6+10
Spring is not used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check javadoc

> *InvalidTopicException*
>
> For example the topic name is too long, contains invalid characters etc.

If you're sending a *valid* topic name, this isn't thrown, and you'll get that warning log instead, which isn't an exception that can be caught.

Also, there's no reason to `throw(e)`. Use `instanceof` to check the type of the Exception in the callback

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: It's specifically not an exception since the broker can be configured to auto create topics that do not exist yet when a client tries to use one... If you really want to check topic existence, use AdminClient

Comment: Basically i am trying to simulate a network error.
In case i lose the connection with the kafka client i need to restart a service rather then continue to send further messages.
Do you perhaps know of a way to handle that scenario?

Comment: In practice, you'd typically have a high replication factor on any topic, spread over different fault domains that would make it highly unlikely for Kafka to be down, but assuming it was, then you'd expect a generic Java network exception, nothing Kafka specific

Comment: I see, haven't considered that, will look into it
thanks again

Comment: The downside of running Kafka replication across availability zones, however, is increased latency and network costs for that higher client availability